# When I make a reference to an object through the list, I cannot reference the properties of the object

Tags: c#, list, object, properties

I'm a beginning programmer, just a couple classes so far but looking to go into software engineering in the future. I'm writing a program that stores movie information as an object in a list of movies.

So every object has movie info, and the list holds all the movie objects. My problem is when I make a reference to an object through the list, I cannot reference the properties of the object.

For example, the Movie object has Name, Genre, etc properties. I reference the list of objects, but when I do this:

```
MovieList[0]
```

The only commands available are default list item functions. How do I reference the list/object so that I can access the properties of the list item?

Comment: Are the properties set to private?

Comment: Do you mean that your IDE just doesn't pop up a list of what is available, or do you mean that when you actually do something like `MovieList[0].Name`, you get a compiler error? Either, way, we'd probably need to see more code, at least the declaration of `MovieList`.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, the way you do this in C# is with a Movie object:

```
public class Movie
{ 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // ..etc
}
```

and a list of Movies:

```
var movies = new List<movie>();
```

to which you can add movies.

```
movies.Add(new Movie { Title = "Saving Private Ryan" });
```

You access the first title of the first movie like this:

```
movies[0].Title
```

Answer (score 1):

How is your list type declared?  If it's declared as `IList`, `ArrayList`, or `List<Object>`, the contents of the list will need to be typecast to your `Movie` type before they can be used.  If, however, you declare the lsit type as `List<Movie>` or `IList<Movie>`, then you should be able to access members of your `Movie` object directly.